# Could someone show me step by step the evaluation of this (Basic/AS Level)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have:

$(1 \frac{9}{16}) ^\frac{3}{2}$

and the answer given is:

$\frac{125}{64}$

I'm not sure the order in which everything was done to get the answer.
Also, does anyone know of a site like WolframAlpha but which shows the step by step progress of a maths problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(1 \frac{9}{16}) ^\frac{3}{2}=(\frac{25}{16})^\frac{3}{2}=((\frac{5}{4})^2)^\frac{3}{2}=(\frac{5}{4})^3=...$$

Comment: That's great, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! It is my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(1 \frac{9}{16} \right)^{3/2} = \left(\frac{25}{16}\right)^{3/2} = \left(\frac{25}{16}\right)^{2/2} \cdot \left(\frac{25}{16} \right)^{1/2} = \frac{25}{16} \cdot \frac{5}{4} = \frac{125}{64}.$$